# Get the ID of selected item in listview

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am making a review application and i am trying to display all the child data from firebase. 
A snip from my firebase is:https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrmNO.png
I can get the data i want in a listview but how do i find out what was pressed so i can send the data to a new activity ? so for example click Bluemoon and can get that data from the database in a new activity?

````
DatabaseReference Reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Beers");
        //DatabaseReference zone1Ref = Reference.child(beerCode);

        listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.allBeersList);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mAllBeers);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.clear();

        Reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //arrayAdapter.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                //arrayAdapter.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                    Beers beers = snapshot.getValue(Beers.class);
                    String beerClass = beers.getmBrewery() + "  " + beers.getmName();

                    arrayAdapter.add(beerClass);



                }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                //Toast.makeText(allBeers.this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(allBeers.this,beerInformation.class);
                //startActivity(intent);
                //Toast.makeText(allBeers.this,beerCode + "",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });```
````

Comment: What's wrong with the shared code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
           //  ListView Clicked item index 
                int itemPosition     = position; 

                // ListView Clicked item value 
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position); 

                // Show Toast 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Position:"+itemPosition+"  Item Clicked: " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG) 
                        .show(); 
                   //Instead of showing a toast here you can pass "itemValue" to another activity as intent

        }
    });
```

Comment: Glad to be of help!